# Reading settings from App.Config

Tags: .net, xml, configuration, app-config, configurationmanager

Config file.

How should I read values of username and password in C# using System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager class? I have tried several stuff but to no avail.

The app.config is given below.

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="Fulfillment.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <applicationSettings>
        <Fulfillment.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="username" serializeAs="String">
                <value>MyUserName</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="password" serializeAs="String">
                <value>MyPassword</value>
            </setting>
        </Fulfillment.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: This is not a valid XML file. I don't see a closing `applicationSettings` element.

Comment: @Oded, it's clearly an excerpt from his web.config file. There are multiple nodes that aren't closed. He's just posting what he felt was relevant.

Comment: @mjw06d - I have learned not to make such assumptions a while back. If he had said that this was an excerpt, then fine.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `appSettings`, not `applicationSettings`? Or does Microsoft use both tags?

Answer (score 7):

If the values are in the appSettings section of the file:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="myUsername" value="david"/>
  <add key="myPassword" value="iLikeHalibut"/>
</appSettings>
```

You can read them as follows:

```
string myUsername = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myUsername"];
```

You will need to make sure the assembly you are programming contains a reference to System.Configuration.dll (it's not always there by default).

Comment: Yeah I know that, I just came across that app.config and tried to read using ConfigurationManager to no avail. But did not about Settings class which can be read via Properties class with your project. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

I use User variables in my application, and access them with:

```
var PropertyValue = Properties.Settings.Default.PropertyName
```

where PropertyName would be MyUserName or MyPassword in your case.

Comment: sorry, I see you edited your post and you are using application values.

Comment: Ok thanks, this works. I did not know that. But there should be a way to read them using ConfigurationManager class. shouldn't it?

Comment: I haven't use the ConfigurationManager before, but FYI, another point I'd like to make is that you probably want to use userSettings and *not* appSettings.  In my experience, appSettings can only be changed by changing the values in Visual Studio and recompiling your app.  appSettings allow you to modify <appname>.exe.config directly.