# How to read/write this app.config setting?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, app-config

Having the following app.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="businessObjects">
      <sectionGroup name="crystalReports">
        <section name="crystalReportViewer" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler" />
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <businessObjects>
    <crystalReports>
      <crystalReportViewer>
        <add key="maxNumberListOfValues" value="5000"/>
      </crystalReportViewer>
    </crystalReports>
  </businessObjects>
```

How would you read and how would you set the setting **maxNumberListOfValues** at runtime? As extra, what if the app.config didnt exist? How would you set the setting dinamically at runtime then?

Comment: Its a variable that uses the Crystal Reports Runtime not our app directly, the problem is that they doesnt show any other way of setting its value...thats why i would like to know how to change this variable value at runtime...

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code to get the app.config file to edit..

```
Configuration configFile = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Also to check whether it is empty or not can use something like

```
            //Check
            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys.Contains(str someKey))
            {
                if (configFile.AppSettings.Settings[str someKey].Value == string.Empty)
                    return true;
            }
            else
            {
                // If app config does not contain needed Keys
                //Handle issue
            }
```

But, case is app.config file is meant to read only values. If you want to edit it on runtime use a user config file. In visual studio there is a file called `settings.Settings` in `properties` folder of your project.Use this.

Comment: Its a variable that uses the Crystal Reports Runtime not our app directly, the problem is that they doesnt show any other way of setting its value...thats why i would like to know how to change this variable value at runtime...

Comment: @ase69s Use the settings.Settings file. You can define the variable as a `user scope` property and change it or read it in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of settings within the app.config is that they're static, constant variables if you will. They're not meant to be changed.

Answers such as this explain reading variables from App Config: [Reading settings from App.Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226816/reading-settings-from-app-config)

If you didn't have the app.config, you'd simply set `maxNumberListOfValues` as a global variable in your solution, in, say, a base file which all your forms/pages inherit from.

Comment: Not entirely true. Application settings can be modified and saved in the ConfigurationSections. Using globals for this is not good practice.

Comment: Its a variable that uses the Crystal Reports Runtime not our app directly, the problem is that they doesnt show any other way of setting its value...thats why i would like to know how to change this variable value at runtime...

Comment: Agreed @Sani Huttunen, but I'd stay away from modifying ConfigurationSections on the fly.